# using a custom build with pbr

Tags: python, setuptools, pybind11, python-pbr

I am trying to use [pbr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbr) for a python package that has an extension module that uses [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). There is a [pybind11 cmake example repo](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/) showing how to use cmake to build an extension module from [setup.py](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py). My question is: How can I incorporate this custom extension module build into a pbr-based setup.py setup.cfg? In particular, how do I use the custom extension classes, CMakeBuild and CMakeExtension, from setup.cfg?

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this? I am facing similar issues where setup.py just behaves unexpectedly, when I use pbr with the classes you mentioned.

Comment: No, I gave up. I submitted a [pbr issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pbr/+bug/1737664) that was turned into a wishlist. Since what I was doing seemed unconventional for pbr, I decided to not try to shoehorn pbr into my efforts.